# Angular 2 with webpack for production environment

Tags: angular, webpack

I am kinda new in Angular 2 and trying to setup `Angular + webpack` by following [Angular official doc](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html) and everything works fine on dev environment but for production, all my files bundled in specific files and `index.html` also got created inside `dist` folder itself, so here how should I load `dist/index.html`.

Comment: upload client & server folder in server hostgator or any  with a root file index.html and add script link of dist client folder index.js in index.html file. check its size we use it for production.

Answer (score 0):

As you have followed the documentation i assume that `webpack-dev-server` is already installed using which you can serve your `dist` folder file after production build:

To serve your production build run : `webpack-dev-server --content-base dist`

Check [webpack dev server](https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html#content-base) documentation for more detail.

Comment: ok its serving index.html from dist but its taking all js files from memory not the one which are in dist folder (minified)

Comment: To add reference to your minified version of your js i think you need to configure https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin inside your `webpack.prod.js`